# Configure existing project on reactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, npm-install

I am a newbie to all reactJS and node so my question is pretty basic.
I have downloaded an already existing project in gitlab using gitbash on my windows system. The project uses ReactJS, node. It also uses webpack. 
Now when I try webpack -w command on gitBash, it is unrecognized. Since its an existing project, the node_modules folder in the directory I am working in ,  has all the needed modules like Webpack, babel etc to name a few. My question is do I still need to install webpack using npm i -g webpack? Currently the webpack command is not working. Or is there a way to tell my git bash(on Windows) to go tell that its already there in the node_modules folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since , you have not installed webpack globally it (npm install webpack -g). `webpack` command is not reconizable by windows terminal . So you have two ways to fix this problem.

1. from your project folder run this command `node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js -w`
2. Install webpack globally so that it works for current and future projects. (npm install webpack -g)

Answer (score 1):

You can use default windows cli, no need in git bash.

If you insatll webpack with `-g` flag, you will install it globally on your system and will be able to access it from everywhere, like this:

```
webpack -w
```

If you didn't install it globally, but still it is installed and located in your local `node_modules`, you can acess it by indicating full path to bin file from cli:

```
node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js  -w
```

Because path is relative, you should be located in the projects directory.